# Can I programmatically place an anonymous phone call?

Tags: android

I have an application from which a user can call another user with the click of a button.

I was wondering whether there was a way to place this call anonymously, hiding the phone number from the user and not saving it in the call history.

Comment: nope, a consumer application but I want to maintain some privacy for my customers

Comment: I hope not. What if you made an app that called 9xx numbers.

Comment: I'm not downvoting this as I'm giving you the benefit of the doubt, but I do hope you're not using it for anything nasty.

Comment: To be honest, I don't think either should be allowed by the platform. As a caller, I want to know who my phone is calling (blocking the Caller ID merely hides it from the recipient) and what charges are going to be incurred. There have been apps known to call surcharged numbers to make money. Allowing this increases risk rather than privacy.

Comment: OK!  Thanks guys.  Not doing anything nefarious, though a lot of my questions probably make it seem so.  I want my customers to be able to contact each other at a particular time, but not have that number saved forever.

Comment: then don't connect them via a telephone call.

Comment: @TomBomb You have got any chance in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the platform source-code there is NO WAY to place a call without the knowledge of the user. The best thing you can do is to make the call automatically but the user will see a dialog saying: "Calling XXXXXXXX" and he will have the chance to cancel it.

Even if you make your own dialer application you will have to sign it with the system key and place it in the system/apps folder in order to get the required permissions for that kind of things.

As for the call log, I don't know if you can make the call not to appear in it in the first place but I think (not sure though) that you can find it and deleted afterwards. Android informs other applications of call actions via Intents so it is relative easy to detect when a call ended and then query the call log.

Hope this helps...